# EF Core querying many-to-many relationship tables

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a question related to querying many-to-many relationship tables.

**For example** `Students` and `Courses` are the main tables whereas `Enrollment` (stores StudentID, CourseID) is the join table.

Given a list of 5 courses on how to find the students who have enrolled exactly to those 5 courses in EF Core?

Comment: if anyone looking for answer, see below link which worked for me.
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621091/ef-core-3-0-convert-sql-to-linq>

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, You need to get list of enrollments like this way

```
var enrollments  = from s in dc.Students
                   from c in s.Courses
                   select new { StudentID = s.StudentID, CourseID = c.CourseID };
```

**Secondly**, you might group by `StudentId`

```
var groupedEnrollment = enrollments.GroupBy(p => p.StudentId)
                                            .Select(g => new 
                                            {
                                                StudentId = g.Key,
                                                Courses = g.Select(p => p.CourseId).ToArray() 
                                            });
```

**Finally**, Select result by condition accordingly.

```
var courses = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var result = groupedEnrollment.Where(g => 
                                         g.Courses.Length == courses.Length && 
                                         g.Courses.Intersect(courses).Count() == courses.Length);
```