# EF Core 3.0 - Convert SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

The example given in [the blog](https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables) has the following

```
from e in s.StudentCourseEnrollments where courseIDs.Contains(e.Course.CourseID) select e
```

The contains logic will not work when we are looking for an exact match. If a student has enrolled for 6 courses (ex : 1,2,3,4,5,6) and the requested list contains 5 (ex: 1,2,3,4,5) the query will return a match when it should not. The other way works well when the student has enrolled in a subset of the requested list.

Below solution works but need help to convert the below sql to LINQ (EF Core 3.0) ?

```
Create TABLE dbo.Enrollments (StudentId INT NOT NULL, CourseId INT NOT NULL)
insert into dbo.Enrollments values (1,1)
insert into dbo.Enrollments values (1,2)
insert into dbo.Enrollments values (1,3)
insert into dbo.Enrollments values (1,4)
insert into dbo.Enrollments values (1,5)
insert into dbo.Enrollments values (1,6)

DECLARE @TempCourses TABLE
(
   CourseId INT
);

INSERT INTO @TempCourses (CourseId) VALUES (1), (2), (3),(4),(5);

SELECT t.StudentId
FROM
(
  SELECT StudentId, cnt=COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.Enrollments
  GROUP BY StudentId
) kc
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT cnt=COUNT(*)
  FROM @TempCourses
) nc ON nc.cnt = kc.cnt
JOIN dbo.Enrollments t ON t.StudentId = kc.StudentId
JOIN @TempCourses n ON n.CourseId = t.CourseId
GROUP BY t.StudentId
HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(nc.cnt);

drop table dbo.Enrollments
```

[db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f9881e834007e8521ededd0901bfe38d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the SQL query, but the EF Core 3.0 LINQ query for the same task is something like this:

```
var matchIds = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.AsEnumerable();
var query = dbContext.Students
    .Where(s => s.Enrollments.All(e => matchIds.Contains(e.CourseId)) 
        && s.Enrollments.Count() == matchIds.Count());
```

The main matching job is done with `All` subquery. Unfortunately that's not enough for the case when related link records are more than the matching ids, so additional counts comparison solves that.

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` isn't required here.

Comment: @JohnyL It's there to indicate that this doesn't need special collection type (array, list, etc.) for ids - any enumerable is sufficient.

Comment: great, it works...but just couple of small changes....new int [] and ToList()

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with a simple way like this, live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hnxw1w)

Let's say that you've got the list of enrollments by this way

```
var enrollments  = from s in dc.Students
                   from c in s.Courses
                   select new { StudentID = s.StudentID, CourseID = c.CourseID };
```

Then get the result by this way

```
    var groupedEnrollment = enrollments.GroupBy(p => p.StudentId)
                                        .Select(g => new 
                                        {
                                            StudentId = g.Key,
                                            Courses = g.Select(p => p.CourseId).ToArray() 
                                        });
    var result = groupedEnrollment.Where(g => 
                                         g.Courses.Length == courses.Length && 
                                         g.Courses.Intersect(courses).Count() == courses.Length);
```

Comment: you are not using the Entrollments table at all. Tried your solution getting LINQ errors. @Ivan solution works great. I accepted his/her answer